# how can we auto find all date variables that are stored as character in a df list and correct it?

Tags: r

I have a strange question: I wonder whether there is a way to auto detect the variable that might be a date variable, and then format it to YYYY-MM-DD? For example, If I have a list `files` which have 5 df (`A,B,C,D, E`). It is possible for us to auto scan those 5 df and find the variables that might be date variable and auto save it to data variable instead of character, and then format them as YYYY-MM-DD?

I am thinking of using `grep`, maybe find the variable the looks like MM/DD/YYYY, then update it as YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: The problem is date variables can be stored a lot of ways, YYYYMMDD, MMDDYY, MM/DD/YYYY, YYYY-MM-DD, YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, B DD, YYYY,  integers, etc. If you want to scan for a specific format or two, it's pretty doable.

Comment: nope. different df might have different variables. So i am thinking using `grep` to detect such variables

Comment: Does it have the same format

Comment: If we only want to detect MM/DD/YYYY, the variable can stay as character, but changed to YYYY-MM-DD, as some might have missing date

Comment: @Stataq can you check the solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the same format, loop over the `list`, create a logical index for `character` column types ('i1'), loop over those character columns, extract the first non-Na element ('x1'), `unlist` the `list`, check for the date format with `grepl` ('i2').  Get the `names` of the original data that have the 'date' format.  Use a condition to only loop over those columns `if` the `length` of the 'nm1' is greater than 0 i.e. if there are any 'date' columns, then loop across those date columns (if there are more than one in a single data) with `lapply`, convert to `Date` class and assign back.  In the end, return the data ('x' )

```
lst1 <- lapply(lst1, function(x)  {
         i1 <- sapply(x, is.character)
         x1 <- lapply(x[i1], function(x) x[complete.cases(x)][1])
         i2 <- grepl("^\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}$", unlist(x1))
         nm1 <- names(x)[i1][i2]
          if(length(nm1) > 0) {
              x[nm1] <- lapply(x[nm1], as.Date, format = '%m/%d/%Y')
         }
           x
        })
```

-output

```
lst1
$`Demographics (DM)`
# A tibble: 6 x 11
  SubjectID  Group          BRTHDTC    SEX   CBPOT CBPYES CBPOTN         CBPOTOTH RACE               RACEOTH ETHNIC             
  <chr>      <chr>          <date>     <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>          <lgl>    <chr>              <chr>   <chr>              
1 101-01-101 Cohort 1: 1mg… 1953-07-07 Fema… No    <NA>   Post-Menopaus… NA       Black / African A… <NA>    Not Hispanic / Not…
2 101-02-102 Cohort 1: 1mg… 1963-07-02 Fema… No    <NA>   Surgically St… NA       White              <NA>    Not Hispanic / Not…
3 101-03-103 Cohort 1: 1mg… 1940-09-11 Male  <NA>  Yes    <NA>           NA       White              <NA>    Not Hispanic / Not…
4 101-04-104 Cohort 1: 1mg… 1955-12-31 Male  <NA>  Yes    <NA>           NA       White              <NA>    Not Hispanic / Not…
5 104-05-201 Cohort 2: 1mg… 1950-12-04 Fema… No    <NA>   Post-Menopaus… NA       White              <NA>    Not Hispanic / Not…
6 101-06-202 Cohort 2: 1mg… 1954-02-19 Fema… No    <NA>   Post-Menopaus… NA       White              <NA>    Not Hispanic / Not…

$`Eligibility Confirmation (EC)`
# A tibble: 6 x 8
  SubjectID  Group             IECYN ICNM  ECNM  ECWAIV ECWAIVDT ECAUTH
  <chr>      <chr>             <chr> <lgl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>    <chr> 
1 101-01-101 Cohort 1: 1mg QD  Yes   NA    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>     <NA>  
2 101-02-102 Cohort 1: 1mg QD  Yes   NA    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>     <NA>  
3 101-03-103 Cohort 1: 1mg QD  Yes   NA    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>     <NA>  
4 101-04-104 Cohort 1: 1mg QD  Yes   NA    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>     <NA>  
5 104-05-201 Cohort 2: 1mg BID Yes   NA    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>     <NA>  
6 101-06-202 Cohort 2: 1mg BID Yes   NA    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>     <NA>  

$`Informed Consent (IC)`
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  SubjectID  Group             ICDT       ICPVDATE                         
  <chr>      <chr>             <date>     <chr>                            
1 101-01-101 Cohort 1: 1mg QD  2018-12-13 Protocol Amendment #1 - 27Sep2018
2 101-02-102 Cohort 1: 1mg QD  2018-12-14 Protocol Amendment #1 - 27Sep2018
3 101-03-103 Cohort 1: 1mg QD  2019-01-04 Protocol Amendment #1 - 27Sep2018
4 101-04-104 Cohort 1: 1mg QD  2019-02-15 Protocol Amendment #1 - 27Sep2018
5 104-05-201 Cohort 2: 1mg BID 2019-03-22 Protocol Amendment #1 - 27Sep2018
6 101-06-202 Cohort 2: 1mg BID 2019-04-05 Protocol Amendment #1 - 27Sep2018
```

Comment: When I tried it, I got error codes `Error: unexpected input in:
"         i1 <- is.character(x)
         i2 <- grepl("^\\d{2}/\\d{2}", \`

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo.  fixed

Comment: Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `i2` has the wrong type `logical`.
i It must be numeric or character.

Comment: @Stataq do you have a matrix or data.frame.  Try to `x[, i2]` or `x[, i2 & i1]`

Comment: I have data.frame. so x should be lst1[["A"]]$x

Comment: @Stataq the issue was that i didn't use the second index, can you try now

Comment: Can you please try now

Comment: Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
x Input has size 11 but subscript `i2 & i1` has size 0.

Comment: @Stataq that implies there are some list elements that doesn't have 'date'

Comment: @Stataq the code works `grepl("^\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}$", c('04/24/1974'))#
[1] TRUE`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232609/discussion-between-stataq-and-akrun).